# Styling StackLayout

Tags: xaml, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I make this work ? My aim is to make a div that fulfills the screen, I'm searching the simpliest and proper way for it, but this does not work.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Background="Red">
  <Button Text="Button Title"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute should be BackgroundColor.

```
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">
      <Button Text="Button Title"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```